# docker-compose is not able to resolve Git URIs from TFS (Team Foundation Server)

Tags: git, docker, tfs, docker-compose

**TL;DR**

Is there any way I can get docker-compose to work with TFS Git URIs?

---

I have written a simple docker-compose.yml that pulls from a repository containing a dockerfile and builds an image.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  ubuntu:    
    image: ubuntu-fromrepo
    build:       
      context: https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu.git
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

When you run this with:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

it will automatically pull the git repository (master branch), build the ubuntu image and run it.

I have a repository on TFS with a dockerfile that works when you pull it manually and run it. So, `git clone ...` to clone the repo, `docker build .` to build the image and then `docker run -it ubuntu:14.04` (for example with the same repo pulled as above in TFS).

However, the docker-compose method that I used above does not work as the Git URI for TFS fails to resolve. It expects a HTTPS Git URI ("https://**server-name**/**repository-name**.git") but in TFS, Git URIs are in the format ("https://**server-name**/tfs/Default/**project-name**/_git/**repository**-name").

docker-compose fails to resolve this URI and outputs this error:

> Service '...' failed to build: {'message': 'error downloading remote context http://.../tfs/Default/.../_git/...: failed to GET http://.../tfs/Default/.../_git/... with status 401 Unauthorized: \r\n ...

*The HTML is just an error page with the following error code :*

Full HTML [here](https://pastebin.com/wfXe2Q37).

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

Is there any way I can get docker-compose to work with TFS Git URIs?

---

UPDATE:

I have tested it with the tokenized URI:

`git clone https://token@servername/tfs/Default/projectname/_git/repositoryname`

which works, but using the same URI in the docker-compose.yml file does not - gives this error:

```
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: error detecting content type for remote http://...@.../tfs/Default/.../_git/...: unsupported Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"`
```

I think this is just returning the error page on TFS for an inaccessible resource?

Comment: What's the rest of that error message?  Seems unlikely that it would be the URL, seems more likely that it's failing to authenticate.

Comment: updated the question and added a link to the HTML error page in pastebin

Comment: Hmm.  `username:pat` really _should_ be the correct format.  Is it possible that your clone test was a false positive?  Might you have a credential helper installed locally?

Answer (score 1):

The example that you've shown (with the `https://github.com/dockerfile/ubuntu.git` URL) assumes that the Git repository is publicly accessible, and does not require authentication.  Your TFS URL, on the other hand, *does* require you to authenticate.

The best way to do this would be by creating a [personal access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts).  This will allow you to both limit access to the resource and support simplified authentication schemes (like HTTP Basic).  Create a personal access token for "Code (read)" and make a note of it.

Now you can specify the personal access token in the URL you use to connect:

```
https://username:personal_access_token@servername/tfs/Default/projectname/_git/repositoryname
```

For example:

```
https://ethomson:a3bwcvdie7figfhriij4krlfmznko7pgqmr7s7tbuwvdw7xiybza@tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Test/_git/testrepo
```

Note that your personal access token is *like a password* and should be secured as such.  If you don't want to store the personal access token directly in the `docker-compose.yml` then you could use an environment variable:

```
services:
  ubuntu:    
    image: ubuntu-fromrepo
    build:       
      context: https://username:${PAT}@servername/tfs/Default/projectname/_git/repositoryname
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Comment: Thanks I think that your imput really helped put me on the right lines - The format of `http://**username**:**token**@....` did not work. 
But, `http://**token**@...` did. Weird. 
I'm just going to test a few things out...

Comment: Got a new error when I use the new URI - `ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: error detecting content type for remote http://...@.../tfs/Default/.../_git/...: unsupported Content-Type "text/html; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: *Sorry - I updated your answer instead of my quesiton by mistake - @moderator can you revert the changes please?*